# Stack Smashing Error MPI_Send() and MPI_Recv()

Tags: c, mpi

I want to resolve stack smashing error in the code

I have tried running the code with mpicc and mpiexec

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank,size,x,status;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if(rank==0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        MPI_Send(&x,1,MPI_INT,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("I have send %d from process 0\n",x);
        //fflush(stdout);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(&x,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        printf("I have received %d in process 1\n",x);
        //fflush(stdout);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the code to print the receiving and sending statements
but the actual output prints the receiving and sending statements 
and gives

> *** stack smashing error ***

I can't understand why does it happen?

Comment: I dont have to do error checking as errors are fatal in MPI by default

Comment: `status` should be of type `MPI_Status`. Might be the cause of your error, might not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `MPI_Status` instead of `int` for declaring the `status` variable, as shown in the code below.

```
#include <mpi/mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank,size,x;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if(rank==0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        MPI_Send(&x,1,MPI_INT,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("I have send %d from process 0\n",x);
        //fflush(stdout);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(&x,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        printf("I have received %d in process 1\n",x);
        //fflush(stdout);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: p.s. I am not sure what you are using to compile the code, but if you use `mpicc` for `C` (OR `mpic++` for `C++`), it should warn you about the _"incompatible pointer type"_ (even in the absence of any additional compiler flags such as `-Wall -Werr -pedantic -Wextra -Wshadow`, etc).